# How to know the exact path to file that was required()

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

In `node` console I do: `require('path')` or `require('assert')` => how to find out exactly which file was loaded by the command (the absolute path to the file)

I couldn't find a decisive answer anywhere and I couln't get to it myself... I thought it would be easier than it seems to be...

Comment: Look up realpath() in the online PHP manual. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is as simple as you were hoping but using the `require` object you can do this:

```
// Load up some modules
var _ = require('lodash');
var natural = require('natural');

// These are where Node will go looking for the modules above
console.log('Paths:');
console.log(require.main.paths);

// You can print out the id of each module, which is the path to its location
console.log('Module IDs:');
require.main.children.forEach((module) => {
    console.log(module.id);
});
```

Output:

```
$ node index.js

Paths:
[ '/Users/tyler/Desktop/js_test/node_modules',
  '/Users/tyler/Desktop/node_modules',
  '/Users/tyler/node_modules',
  '/Users/node_modules',
  '/node_modules' ]

Module IDs:
/Users/tyler/Desktop/js_test/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
/Users/tyler/Desktop/js_test/node_modules/natural/lib/natural/index.js
```

As far as I can tell the module IDs will be in the order that you `require` them, so you should be able to work with their indexes or search through the module ids dynamically for whatever you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me because `require.main` is undefined... do you know why?

Comment: I would just `console.log(require)` and see what the object looks like

Comment: yes, when I do it I see that `main` property on it is `undefined`.. is this abnormal? Can you just run node and do the same? What is the value of your `require.main` ?